# Tkinter Button Alignment in Grid

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I am attempting to fit two buttons on a grid within a frame, that takes up the entire row, no matter the size of the root frame. So essentially one button takes up half of the row, while the other takes the other half. Here's my code:

```
self.button_frame = tk.Frame(self)
self.button_frame.pack(fill=tk.X, side=tk.BOTTOM)

self.reset_button = tk.Button(self.button_frame, text='Reset')
self.run_button = tk.Button(self.button_frame, text='Run')

self.reset_button.grid(row=0, column=0)
self.run_button.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

Not really sure where to go from here. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `columnconfigure` to set the weight of your columns. Then, when the window stretches, so will the columns. Give your buttons `W` and `E` sticky values, so that when the cells stretch, so do the buttons.

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

button_frame = tk.Frame(root)
button_frame.pack(fill=tk.X, side=tk.BOTTOM)

reset_button = tk.Button(button_frame, text='Reset')
run_button = tk.Button(button_frame, text='Run')

button_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
button_frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

reset_button.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)
run_button.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)

root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]