# Using self.pack and self.grid works without classes, but fails with them

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter, tk-toolkit

So I tried to use [Tkinter Button Alignment in Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22559290/tkinter-button-alignment-in-grid) to make a toolbar, but the difference is im using classes. So while they use frame.pack and button.grid, i get the error of using both pack and grid. Here is my code:

```py
class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.master.title('Hi!')
        self.master.configure(bg='dark grey')
        self.pack(fill=X, side=TOP)
        self.create_toolbar()

    def create_toolbar(self):
        Home = Button(text='Home', bd=1)
        About = Button(text='About', bd=1)

        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        Home.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W+E)
        About.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W+E)
```

Comment: What error?  On what line?  Don't make us guess...

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the whole reason I made the question...
`Home.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W+E)`
`_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack`

Comment: You already have a class with (tk.Tk) ? Please make a quick exampel to copy and paste it. Otherwise I will give you the wrong answer.

Comment: I thhink you need to set `master` of the buttons to `self`.

Comment: How would i do that?

Comment: `Button(self, text='Home', bd=1)`

Comment: Oh wow!! Thanks, that worked!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a parent/master that initialize a tkinter class?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59008955/7414759)

Comment: Yes, thanks. It worked perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the issue here is that the Widgets don't have master set, so they are defaulting to the class' master, where you have already used pack for geometry management.

The solution here is to set `master=self` when you are declaring your widgets, then when you go to place the widgets in the tk.Frame object you can use grid.